# Error in XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

MySQL was working last night and i used it for the past 2 months without an error occured, but this morning it suddenly gave an error

```
   10.00.17  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
   10.00.17  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
   10.00.17  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
   10.00.17  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
   10.00.17  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
   10.00.17  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
   10.00.17  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

this is the error log

```
    InnoDB: using atomic writes.
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
    Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 47091; transaction id 9
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200810 10:00:15
    2020-08-10 10:00:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

i've tried change the port from 3306 to 8111, i dont have skype installed, delete the ib files(buffer pool, logfile0, logfile1, and ibdata1),and i've tried to run as administrator.

What is going on and how to fix this problem? Thanks

Ps : Everytime i try to quit xampp, this error pop-up appears
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyYip.jpg)

Comment: I had to reinstall XAMPP

Comment: yes it solved thx